# Safely Display Card PIN

Tags: appsec, credit-card, sms

We are currently sending the card PIN via SMS. We do not store them in any way, neither do we have the possibility to change it. The only way to change it is for the customer to go to an ATM and change it there.

We face a lot of customer incidents due to the SMS never arriving *(it is a problem with the vendor)*.

Since we are facing this problem, we want to display the PIN in-app. The vendor provides us with an endpoint (that must be accessed through a machine-to-machine VPN) where we can query the card PIN.

Our idea is to display this PIN in-app, so we do not depend on the vendor's ability to deliver SMS.

We want to achieve the same level of security as if we were sending the PIN using SMS.

As of now, to request the PIN, the customer needs to log in using their credentials (we use Auth0 for authentication), then hit a button and wait for the PIN to arrive at their mobile phone. The mobile phone is set by the customer when they first request the card and it cannot be changed afterwards. Once logged, the session is refreshed automatically.

What security measures should we include to achieve this goal?

**TL;DR** we want to replace sending the PIN via SMS to displaying it in-app. What steps should we take to make them both equally safe.

Comment: Do you only send the sms after providing a new card, for the initial PIN? What are you currently doing if the user requests the PIN again? What happens if the customer requests a PIN sms after changing it at an ATM?

Comment: @Ángel we send the pin each time the customer request it on the app. If they change it, the next time they request it, they will receive the new one